# How to get DatatTable in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google Dashboard, Charts and Wrapper class in my website. I wrote a simple test app for it which I bring it below;

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls','charteditor']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael' , 5],
          ['Elisa', 7],
          ['Robert', 3],
          ['John', 2],
          ['Jessica', 6],
          ['Aaron', 1],
          ['Margareth', 8]
        ]);

        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
          }
        });

        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
    'dataTable': data,
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        });
  var chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', redrawChart);
     
  
  // On "OK" save the chart to a <div> on the page.
  function redrawChart(){
   chartEditor.getChartWrapper().draw(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, chartEditor.getChartWrapper());
  }
        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, wrapper);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
  
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = "Edit me";
  button.onclick = () => chartEditor.openDialog(wrapper, {});
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  
  setInterval(updateChart, 5000);
  function updateChart() 
  {
   let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
      /************* THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES IS WORKING ****************************/
   data.addRow(['Reza' + rand, rand]); 
   dashboard.draw(data);
      /************* THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES IS NOT WORKING ****************************/
   //wrapper.getDataTable().addRow(['Reza' + rand, rand]);
   //dashboard.draw(wrapper.getDataTable());
  }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the "getDataTable" function of my chart wrapper does not have a "addRow" function. It seems that it returns a DataView instead of DataTable. I don't want to keep a reference of my data because it should be in the wrapper! Anyway, Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you draw the dashboard, it appears to override the data table on the wrapper with a data view

this can easily be changed back to a normal data table using method --> `toDataTable()`

```
var wrapperData = wrapper.getDataTable().toDataTable();
wrapperData.addRow(['Reza' + rand, rand]);
dashboard.draw(wrapperData);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls', 'charteditor']
}).then(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
    ['Michael' , 5],
    ['Elisa', 7],
    ['Robert', 3],
    ['John', 2],
    ['Jessica', 6],
    ['Aaron', 1],
    ['Margareth', 8]
  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div')
  );

  var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Donuts eaten'
    }
  });

  var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      legend: 'right'
    }
  });

  var chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', redrawChart);

  function redrawChart(){
    chartEditor.getChartWrapper().draw(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, chartEditor.getChartWrapper());
  }

  dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, wrapper);
  dashboard.draw(data);

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = "Edit me";
  button.onclick = () => chartEditor.openDialog(wrapper, {});
  document.body.appendChild(button);

  setInterval(updateChart, 5000);
  function updateChart() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

    var wrapperData = wrapper.getDataTable().toDataTable();
    wrapperData.addRow(['Reza' + rand, rand]);
    dashboard.draw(wrapperData);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```